# How does $x^4+y^4=z^2 \implies x^4+y^4=z^4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Why is the statement "the following cannot be satisfied" for $x^4+y^4=z^2$ more strong than for $x^4+y^4=z^4?$

More specifically, how does $x^4+y^4=z^2 \implies x^4+y^4=z^4?$

This statement was found on page 4 of the following [document](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~jalbert/courses/davis_miller.pdf).

Comment: Because $\;z^4=(z^2)^2\;$

Comment: If $x^4+y^4=z^2$ has no positive integer solutions, $x^4+y^4=z^4$ cannot have any positive integer solution.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hi, why does what you commented cause the implication? I don't follow.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Hi, this is exactly what I'm asking, is why your comment is true.

Comment: If you have a solution to $\;x^2+y^2=z^2\;$ , then you also have one to $\;x^2+y^2=(z^2)^2=z^4\;$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is mistaken: you have not correctly understood what is written in the document that you refer to. Of course that if $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x^4 + y^4 = z^2$, it does *not* follow that it also satisfies $x^4 + y^4 = z^4$ *unless* $z^2 = z^4$ (i.e. $z \in \{-1,0,1\}$), which is very restrictive and not what that author meant to say.

What is meant there is that if $(x,y,z)$ satisfies $x^4 + y^4 = z^4$, then there exist *another* triple $(X,Y,Z)$ satisfying $X^4 + Y^4 = Z^2$ (and that triple is precisely $(X,Y,Z) = (x,y,z^2)$).

Comment: Dear @Majid, you deleted your own answer at 18:21:22, and the (correct) answers given by me and "Topological cat" got downvoted at 18:23:36 and, respectively, at 18:21:37 (the latter, remarkably, only 15 seconds after the deletion of your answer!). Remarkable coincidence! Do I report it to a moderator, or would you rather apologize? And, in general, revenge votes are not the solution; learning mathematics better is. It is not our fault that you have graduated in mathematics yet you make gymnasium-level mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

If it had a solution $(x,y,z)$, then $(x,y, z^2)$ is solution of the first one

Comment: You got downvoted (like me) by @Majid: he felt embarassed that he gave the wrong answer which got him 3 downvotes. Ridiculous. (See also my own comment under my answer).

Comment: @AlexM. he first suggested an edit to my answer, changing "of the first one" to "of the second one". It might be a little confusing to correctly say which implies the other, though the concept is there, such things can confuse anybody, and I suppose that everybody can relate to this. So it's an understandable mistake, he didn't have to make such a big deal out of it!

Comment: As a side note, you also suggested a modification to his answer (turning it into a correct one), but I have rejected it: if a user is active on MSE, it is more polite to signal his errors (unless they are minor) in comments (as I have done); significant edits of other people's answers, even if mathematically correct, are intrusive and aggressive because they change the meaning originally intended by their authors. Even a mistaken answer deserves some respect. Otherwise, welcome to MSE!